# Rails - form_tag with :remote => true and false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, redirect

I have a form with `:remote => true`, where is `button` and `submit_tag` for sending form.
When I send form through **button**, I would need to send the form as `:remote => true` and render some data through AJAX, which works me well.

But if a user send form through the **submit_tag**, I would need to execute some operations and then **redirect_to** an another page.

Is there any way, how to do it with **:remote => true** in the form head?

Thanks

Comment: The submit and button are in the same form?

Comment: Yes, in the same form.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is how I have solved it:

```
render js: %(window.location.href='#{root_url}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jsvascript. Add remote attribute to form dynamically on button click.